# Mongodb build/compile error: not enough memory on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Preface so this isn't marked as a duplicate: I've seen lots of mongodb memory issues posted on stack overflow, but none that have to do with errors on the compilation.

I just freshly downloaded and ran Ubuntu on Virtualbox (on a mac), so I feel like there should be enough memory. However, when I try to compile Mongodb from the source code I've gotten the following errors about an hour into the compilation (I have done this a few times now)

```
scons: *** [<whatever file it was working on>] No space left on device
scons: building terminated because of errors
```

and on a separate occasion

```
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device:
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1359:
        _exec_main(parser, values)
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1323:
        _main(parser)
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1072:
        nodes = _build_targets(fs, options, targets, target_top)
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1281:
       jobs.run(postfunc = jobs_postfunc)
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 113:
        postfunc()
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1278:
       SCons.SConsign.write()
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/SConsign.py", line 109:
       syncmethod()
    File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/dblite.py", line 117:
       self._pickle_dump(self._dict, f, 1)
Exception IOError: (28, 'No space left on device') in <bound method dblite.__del__ of <SCons.dblite.dblite object at 0x7fbe2a577dd0>> ignored
```

I've tried both of the following build commands:

```
scons all --dbg=on -j1
scons --dbg=on -j1
```

According to VirtualBox the virtual size is 8 GB and the Actual size is 4.09 GB. Also, if it makes the difference, the odds that the memory on my mac is actually full is slim to none.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've tried creating more memory (24 GB) and resizing partitions but I still cannot complete a build. 
Here is the output of the `df -T` command:

```
Filesystem     Type       1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4        15345648  14304904     238184  99% /
none           tmpfs              4         0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs     1014316        12    1014304   1% /dev
tmpfs          tempfs        205012       860     204152   1% /run
none           tempfs          5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none           tempfs       1025052       152    1024900   1% /run/shm
none           tempfs        102400        40     102360   1% /run/user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say memory, I believe you mean disk space. Try running the command

`df -T` to see what % usage you really have. You will probably need to resize the amount of space virtualbox has assigned to your image, as well as resize your repartition. It may be simpler to just create a new virtualbox image with 16 or 24GB of disk space.

If you decide to go the resize partition route, here is a helpful resource: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately, I tried both and neither seem to work. First I started ubuntu freshly with 24GB and then when that didn't work I tried moving the partitions of that machine around about, still nothing. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Whats the output of `df -T`?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I've added the output as an edit to the question, Thanks again

Comment: Your main file system partition size is now 16GB (not 24GB). As you can see it's 99% full. You will need to try recreating your VM again with even more space. This link (from 2011) mentions that it needed 16GB diskspace 2 years ago. It's probably a bit more than that now :( http://notesoncomputing.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/installing-mongodb-on-openbsd-4-9-part-1-compiling/

Comment: thanks for catching my mistake on the typing and more importantly the memory issue. It build with default memory partitions of 24GB and used up 99% of the memory so I resized the partition for good measure afterward